# How to call a click event from within an HTML select tag

Tags: php, html

I have a submit button named 'dump'. I want to remove it from the document because if the user forgets to click it, it ruins two tables. Instead, what I'd like to do is put it here in the onchange event:

```
<select class="form-control" id="groupid" name="groupid" onchange="this.form.submit(); '<?php echo $_POST["dump"] ?>'">
```

But this isn't working. And maybe I'm doing this wrong. **How can I trigger the click event of the Dump button**:

```
if($_POST['dump']) { ... }
```

when the groupid select box changes and the:

```
onchange="this.form.submit();"
```

is called? How can this be done programmatically so that I can rid the document of the Dump button?

Answer (score 1):

I think your submit button is named "submit". Therefore, form.submit refers to the button rather than the method. Rename the button or remove it .

**BTW**

> As a general rule, auto-submitting forms when a control changes is a
>   really bad idea from a usability and accessibility standpoint. See
>   [WCAG - F36: Failure of Success Criterion 3.2.2 due to automatically
>   submitting a form and presenting new content without prior warning
>   when the last field in the form is given a value](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/F36.html) and [WCAG - G13:
>   Describing what will happen before a change to a form control that
>   causes a change of context to occur is made](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G13.html)

example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="myform">
  <select class="form-control" id="groupid" name="groupid">
    <option name="name" value="0">0</option>
    <option name="name" value="1">1</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" id="dump" name="dump" value="Dump" class="btn btn-danger">
</form>

<script>
  $(function() {

    $("#groupid").on('change', function(e) {
      $('#dump').trigger('click'); //trigger Dump click event
    });
    $('#dump').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); //prevent submit action
      console.log('Dump button click event call')
      $(this).attr('value', 'Dump button click event call')
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: I edited my post to show you the name of the button. And the form.submit is only to load a select box, not to submit a form for processing. But thanks for your input.

Comment: @Landslyde remove  '<?php echo $_POST["dump"] ?>'  in your onchange code , cauz it is not valid js code, so onchange never call this.form.submit()

Comment: The form.submit works fine, Felix_Ho. I just need to know to trigger the click event for the Dump button so I can remove it from the document. I need the Dump event to be triggered when the form.submit action takes place. That is what I need help with. If I can't do that in the onchange with the form.submit, then how can it be triggered when the form.submit is triggered?

Comment: @Landslyde do you use jquery?

Comment: @Landslyde do you just want to bind two select elements in a form?

Comment: I've never used it, no. Is there a way to trigger the Dump button click event using that? I need to be able to trigger the click event for the Dump button when the form.submit() occurs so I can remove that button from my document. Can JQuery accomplish this? If so, please tell me how to do this. I'm willing to try anything at this point.

Comment: What do you mean by binding two select elements? I don't understand that. Sorry.

Comment: @Landslyde when form.submit() call , the page will reload , it make no sense to remove anything from the document

Comment: In no way are you addressing my concern, Felix_Ho. You're talking abt everything but what I'm trying to get an answer to.

Comment: @Landslyde FYI. <select class="form-control" id="groupid" name="groupid" onchange="var obj = document.getElementById('dump'); obj.parentNode.removeChild(obj);">

Comment: So I can have one JQuery function that both submits AND simulates a button click? Is that right?

Comment: @Landslyde check my post , there is a jquery example, you can run the code snippet.

Comment: I like that. So I can also add the submit to that too? And when #groupid changes, submit also gets called? I need both to happen at the same time: submit and button click.

Comment: @Landslyde your Dump button is an input element with type="submit", when it trigger the click event it will do submit action , i use this code   "e.preventDefault();" to prevent that , if you remove it then submit will gets called. btw, [jQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/) can do almost every thing you want .

Comment: You've been a great help to me, Felix_Ho, opening my eyes to JQuery. I didn't know it was so powerful.  I hope i can return the favor one day. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

simply:

1) use the `hidden="hidden"` attriute on the dump button

2) use `onchange="document.getElementById('dump').click();"` attribute on the place where u want the event to trigger afterchange, then what should be done when clicked on dump, will be triggered onchange, where you add the onchange event.

Comment: if this solves your problem, tick it as an answer so others with same problem benefits from it :)

Answer (score 0):

as you explained, I think all you want is to hide the button so,

use style='visibility:hidden' for dump(submit button)

Comment: What I want to do is completely remove the Dump button and have its click event triggered in the onchange, as I stated in my post.